# Java SpringBoot Logging File Config

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback

I am using the following properties in my application so that it starts rolling on a daily basis. I am currently using the properties mentioned below, but struggling to configure the log files location.

```
logging.file.name=myservice.log
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.file-name-pattern=myservice-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size=100K
```

It almost works fine but when I use the properties listed above, it starts putting the log files in a random dir (say /opt/logs). If I append the directory path (say /dev/logs) with the first and second property, the rolling stops working altogether.

Apparently logging.file.path is deprecated and I shouldn't be using it. What am I missing?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Using *logging.file* property should help

You may use *logging.file* one of the following way:

```
logging.file = logfile.log                     //in current folder
logging.file = relativepath/to/logfile.log     //relative path with filename
logging.file = /fullpath/to/logfile.log        //full path with filename
```